pour concrete in +1C with rain
My contractor poured concrete today at my house, the floors, armed with steel (I hope I am explaining it properly).
It was +1C and it was raining. It had the Sika additive, 1% for -5C conditions. The rain was very light in the beginning, but then it picked up, quite a lot, I could see paddles on it while they were making it straight. They finished at around 2PM, covered it with plastic, and in the next few days there will be +6/+8C the average temperature outside, but it will stil rain.
After about 8 hours, I went there and touched it, it is still very much soft. There are puddles of water on the plastic. Honestly, was this a terrible idea from my contractor and how bad is my situation?
After 36h it got much stronger, but if you press hard enough, it seems still not ideal.
Thank you.

Concrete takes close to 28 days to cure completely.
It should be surface hard in a day or two.
It should also be kept a bit damp for a few days(a heavy mist).  You do not want the surface of the concrete covered in puddles, just enough to keep the surface damp.  Puddles on the plastic should be okay.
It seems as everything is okay, they used the additive for the cold and covered it with plastic to not get too wet.
